# Merge two lists into Linked Data Source. LinkTitle not working?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

Using SharePoint Designer 2010 I created a Linked Data Source that merges two lists.
Then I inserted a Data View and select the linked data source I created.
The problem is that I want the Title to be a link to display the selected item,  but when I insert the LinkTitle field it does not include a link, just the Title text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by using one of these links with the title.

Link to view item in popup window

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('{@FileDirRef}/DispForm.aspx?ID={@ID}');"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>
```

View item without popup. The GoToLink adds "source" to URL so it will return to the site with the link.

```
<a href="{@FileDirRef}/DispForm.aspx?ID={@ID}" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a>
```